# Is there an easy way to start to use Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, web

Today I made my first attempt to use Twitter bootstrap and it failed. I tried to follow the instructions from [here](http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/tutorial.php).

First, I used `git clone git://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git` to download the bootstrap. As a result I got directory called `bootstrap` with all the subdirectories and files. Then I created a test html file to which I copy-pasted html code from [here](http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/layout-tutorial.php). Then I opened this html file in my browser. It did not look like it was supposed to look.

Then I have realized that the html code tries to read bootstrap from `twitter-bootstrap-v2` not from `bootstrap`. OK, I have renamed the `bootstrap` directory. After that the html file looked better but not as it was supposed to look.

Then I have realized that html code tries to "read" `example-fixed-layout.css` file that does not exists. OK, I have created this file by copy-paste css code from that same page that contains html code. After that my html code looked better but still not the same way as it was supposed to look.

Then I have realized that the css code in `example-fixed-layout.css` has a link to `/twitter-bootstrap/images/gridbg.gif` and in the downloaded directories I do not have this image. At this point I gave up.

Is there an easy way to start using Twiter bootstrap?

Moreover, I am confused by the fact that I need to "Compile CSS and JavaScript" (as it is written [here](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap)). How css ot JavaScript can be compiled? Are there such thing as executable css?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to compile...

A very simple way to get started is to reference the Bootstrap CSS and JS on from [**BootstrapCDN**](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) right in your HTML.

**Complete CSS**

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Complete JavaScript**

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Also check out [**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com) which is a HTML/JS/CSS Editor just for Bootstrap. This is any easy way to see how the different Bootstrap styles, elements and components work.

Answer (score 2):

## 0. Downloading the proper package

[Click Here.](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/bootstrap.zip)

([source](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html#download-bootstrap))

## 1. Adding to the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="/bootsrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="/bootsrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

([source](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html#html-template))

## 2. Compiling

...is not neccessary, it's already compiled in the package. The compling is mentioned because Bootstrap is originally written in SASS and it needs to be compiled to a normal CSS file, but the guys @ bootstrap already did it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply download the zip file of the compiled version  (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/bootstrap.zip) and include the CSS/JS in your page templates.

Compiling is only necessary if you are using the *source* version.

See http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/getting-started.html