# Why cant I see bootstrap classes--html file on local drive

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

A very simple way to get started with Bootstrap is to reference the Bootstrap CSS and JS on from BootstrapCDN right in your HTML. No need to compile...(Following instructions in ref 2)
Before diving into Bower, I want to explore dependencies manually.So I open this file in Chrome. Angular works. The css classes do not.
In the html, are the references pointing correctly? If so why are my classes not displaying? Its been days and there must be some big elephant in the room that I am not seeing.

```
    <html ng-app>
    <head>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js'>           </script>
    <!-- Bootstrap
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 -->
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

```
 <body ng-init="what = 'Angularjs'">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar">
       <div class="navbar-inner">
         <a class="brand" href="#">Quick Start</a>
         <ul class="nav">
             <li><a ui-sref="route1">Route 1</a></li>
             <li><a ui-sref="route2">Route 2</a></li>
             <li ng-class="{ active: $state.includes('blue') }">
                <a href="#/blue">Blue</a>
             </li>
             <li ng-class="{ active: $state.includes('green') }">
                <a href="#/green">Green</a>
             </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>

      <div  class="row">
        <div class="span12">
        <div class="well" ui-view></div>
      </div>
      </div>

       Now your cooking with {{what}}!
       <hr/>
       {{"hello"+" world"}}
       <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947084/how-to-host-an-angularjs-app-in-domain  ">Ref 1</a>
       <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459363/is-there-an-easy-way-to-start-to-use-twitter-bootstrap ">Ref 2</a>
       </div>
       <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins)
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>   -->
       <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed
       <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  -->

       <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: add http: before the netdna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

instead of:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

sometimes without the "http:" it doesn't work.

Comment: I also found that <style type='text/css'>
    @import url('http://txt.fliglio.com/bootstrap.css');


</style> worked but i read somewhere that this was an old school way to do it. Anyway thanks for fixin' my broken heart. I am all smiles now and ready to tackle ui-router again.